# Command to kill connection with specific URL or with Specific HTTP status

Tags: fiddler

I am aware of command line utility of fiddler known as

```
ExecAction.exe
```

I am able to save session via command line like this-

```
ExecAction.exe dump
```

Is there any way to Kill specific connection? Or Kill all the connection with specific HTTP result.
Example- Lets say close all connection having string "google.com". Kill all connection with HTTP status code 304.

I tried following but does not work out-

```
ExecAction.exe bps 304
```

Thanks.

Comment: selecting a host is via command "@host", but how to close connection is what i need now.

Comment: Thank you Eric for your reply. I want to close the connection when client gets connected with server and get HTTP response 200 or 304.

Comment: I need to kill connection "after the server's reply is sent to the client".

Comment: Not sure about this statement "Which connection do you want to kill, the client's connection to Fiddler, or Fiddler's connection to the server?" I just want to kill the connection which connects client to server. Whats the difference between client's connection to Fiddler and Fiddler's connection to the server?

Comment: Cool!! So i need to kill the connection with client to fiddler via command line. Please guide me to achieve this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've said that your goal is to close the connection after the server replies to the client. The simplest way to do that would be to click Rules > Customize Rules. Scroll to **OnBeforeResponse** and add the code:

```
if (oSession.HostnameIs("google")) {
  oSession.oResponse["Connection"] = "close";
}
```

This will cause Fiddler to close the connection after returning the response.

Comment: Awesome Eric!! But how to do it via program without any manual work?

Comment: I don't understand the premise of your question. The script provided will close the connection.